# File does not output when adding the date to it

Tags: c++, datetime, stringstream, fileoutputstream

I would like to output an error report for my code with a filename formatted as "ErrorReport_date_time.rpt". as of right now i can output a file as "ErrorReport.rpt" or with no extension but when adding the date and time, it does not create a file.

```
void ErrorHandler::Open(char const filename[])
{
    string fileType = ".rpt";

    time_t t = time(0);
    struct tm * now = localtime(&t);

    stringstream ss;

    ss << filename
       << (now->tm_year + 1900) << '-'
       << (now->tm_mon + 1) << '-'
       << (now->tm_mday) << '_'
       << (now->tm_hour) << ':'
       << (now->tm_min) << ':'
       << now->tm_sec
       << fileType
       << endl;

    fileHandler->OpenFile(ss.str());
}
```

Supposing that my file handler opens, closes, and writes to a file successfully, where would I be going wrong?

Comment: You're going wrong by failing to provide a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Why `endl` is added to the file name?

Comment: What OS? Windows can't have `:` and similar characters in filenames afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `:` or `endl` in file names.

Comment: For such a small oversight, it really did provide a lot of heart ache for me, this is in fact the correct answer and has alleviated the issue!

Comment: On Windows, `:` *can* be used in a filename, if the file system is NTFS. Using `:` allows creation of a [data stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404.aspx) within the file specified by the filename preceeding the `:`. For example, a filename of `file:strm` creates a stream named `strm` in the file named `file`.